# com.databricks.spark.csv version requirement

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

Which version of `com.databricks.spark.csv` is compatible for Spark 1.6.1, and scala 2.10.5?
I can see

```
com.databricks_spark-csv_2.10-1.5.0.jar
com.databricks_spark-csv_2.11-1.3.0.jar
```

already available on my machine, and as per my understanding goes, if I have `scala version 2.10`, then the first option is the one that I have to use. just wanted to re-confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the first jar as you have scala 2.10 on your machine

```
com.databricks_spark-csv_2.10-1.5.0.jar
```

As 2.10 means it is meant for scala 2.10